# Cache remotely accessed websites

Tags: php, caching, curl, centos

I have an application that often retrieves remote websites(via cURL), and I was wondering what are my options regarding to caching of those HTTP requests. For example:

```
application -->curl-->www.example.com
```

The issue is that cURL could be called hundreds of times in an hour, and every time would need to make hundreds of HTTP requests, that are basically the same. So, what I could to speed things up ? I was experimenting with [Traffic server](http://trafficserver.apache.org/) but wasn't very satisfied with  results. I guess DNS caching is a must, but what else I can do here? The system that the app is running on is CentOS.

Comment: You could use the file system or a database and store the curl response there.  Give it a TTL and refresh when needed.  Very common scenario, try just googling 'caching'?  Are you asking specifically about what to use for the persistence layer?

Comment: well storing the response in a database involves changing a lot of code in the app that doesn't support any kind of caching, so I wanted to solve this at the OS level. If I would go in that direction(database), would Memcached be a good place to store HTTP Response and HTTP headers ?

Comment: Depends on the size of the HTML response you are caching.  Key/Value stores like memecache are not ideal for storing "large" values.  Difficulty of adding I/O with memcache vs RDBMS vs filesystem is pretty similar... Might depend more on... mutex needs, available memory, other considerations you are aware of...  Using the files system you could always also add something like [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) or Traffic Server on top.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented caching using the filesystem as a store, and it works really fast now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Traffic Server didn't provide satisfiable results, but in general a Forward Proxy setup with caching is the way to do this. You would of course make sure that the response from www.example.com is cacheable, either via configurations on the caching proxy server, or directly on the origin (example.com). This is probably the biggest confusion in the proxy caching world, the expectations of what is cacheable or not does not meet the requirements.